# WordPress custom taxonomy templates

Tags: wordpress, redirect, taxonomy

I have a lot of different custom taxonomies and each one has specific template (taxonomy-customtax.php)

For now the templates are placed in the root of my theme.

Since we are able to place some template files in a subfolder (except for archive template), I would like to know if the following code is a correct way to do?

The code is in taxonomy.php in root of my theme:

```
<?php

$taxonomy = get_queried_object()->taxonomy;

if ($taxonomy == 'customtax')
{
    get_template_part('template/customtax');
    exit;
}

wp_safe_redirect(site_url('/'));
exit;

?>
```

Is there any problem if do that way?
Thank you

Comment: Am not sure about your idea. But, the thing to remember here is, `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, and taxonomy's term were someterm WordPress would look for taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php. In the case of Post Formats `post-format-{format}`. i.e. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php`

Comment: Thanks I know that, but I can do that only if templates are located in the root of my theme, what I want is to get custom templates in a subfolder of my theme. What would be wrong for you?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly that should work just fine. But as soon as you get my different post types or taxonomies, you would get a huge conditional script. Lets say, you have a archive page. You want to display the article teasers with different content and design for each post type or taxonomy. I would recommend you for example the following:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/teaser', get_post_type()); ?>
<?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_type()); ?>
```

or for a taxonomy term (i.E. Category):

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); get_template_part('templates/teaser', echo $category[0]->cat_name); ?>
<?php $category = get_the_category(); get_template_part('templates/content', echo $category[0]->cat_name); ?>
```

Note that this taxonomy solution only works for posts wich are assigned to a single taxonomy term. Hope you like the idea of handling it that way. I got wordpress sites up and running with 5-6 custom post types and 2-3 custom taxonomies and just one index.php as archive base.